# multiple select display issue on IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, multiple-select

I'm using multiple selects on different pages of my website, which work perfectly.
I've specified a height and a size for my multiple select, in order not to display its 100 items...
The problem ? When testing my form on IE9, I've noticed that when I select one ore many items in my select, the "hidden" items (I mean the items below the the bottom of the select) appear below my select :

```
 +-------------------------------------+
 | Item1                               |
 | Item2                               |
 | Item3                               |
 +-------------------------------------+
                    ...
 +-------------------------------------+
 | Some content(div, textarea, etc.    |
 +-------------------------------------+
```

and then:

```
   Item9
   Item10
   Item11
   ...
```

These items are displayed over the following parts of my page.
Sometimes it disappear when playing with the mouse scroll.
And when the multiple select is no longer visible on the page, the "bug" disappears"...

I'm trying to fix this issue since hours, and I must say... I need some help :)
I can't find out the origin of this problem.
I think that the select inherits from a css attribute, which is not understood by IE9. But I can't find it.

Is there a way to "RESET" the inherited css attributes ?
Is there a way to test my CSS file compatibility with IE9 ?

In brief, any help would be really, really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

plastic1st

PS : nothing special in my code :

```
<select name="counties[]" id="counties__" multiple="multiple" size="5" class="required" title="<?php echo FORM_COUNTIES_LABEL; ?> : <?php echo FORM_COUNTIES_HELP; ?>">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
$i=0;
    foreach($counties as $county)
    {
        echo "<option value='".$county->fieldtitle."' id='county_".$i++."'>".$county->fieldtitle."</option>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Your PHP is not helpful in answering this question because PHP is 100% on the server and your problem is 100% in the client. Please show your rendered HTML and related CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Diodeus and thank you for your answer !!
Here is the rendered HTML :

```
<select name="counties[]" id="counties__" multiple="multiple" size="5" style="height:70px">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="01 - Ain" id="county_0">01 - Ain</option>
<option value="02 - Aisnes" id="county_1">02 - Aisnes</option>
...
<option value="976 - Mayotte" id="county_100">976 - Mayotte</option>
</select>
```

I have skipped the css style sheets. So the only specified settings are the size and the height.
I don't understand at all. I feel that there os something on the page that IE can not understand.

I have tried to insert this multiple select on another page, and I had the same problem, 
which I have solved by skipping some of the CSS settings (for example, a "@font-face" setting, clearly not digetsed by IE9...)
But back to my page, I don't succeed in fixing the bug...
It drives me crazy...